# LTI systems inverse of each other

Tags: continuous-signals, linear-systems, homework, self-study

So my question looks like this:

> Suppose that we have two LTI systems with impulse responses 
>   $$h_1(t) = \frac 12\delta(t-1)\quad\text{and}\quad h_2(t)=2\delta(t+1).$$
>   Determine whether these systems are inverses of one another.

Here's what I've done but I'm stuck. I'd appreciate some help with this

$$h_1(t)\star h_2(t)\overset{?}{=}\delta(t)$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_1(\tau)h_2(t-\tau)d\tau &=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac12\delta(\tau-1)2\delta(t-\tau+1)d\tau\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(\tau-1)\delta(t-\tau+1)d\tau\\
\end{align}

$$u = \tau - 1\implies \frac{du}{d\tau}=1\implies du = d\tau$$

$$\implies \int_{-\infty}^\infty h_1(\tau)h_2(t-\tau)d\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(u)\delta(t-u)d\tau$$

Comment: Welcome to SP.SE!  Your question appears to be homework / self-study, however you've asked it as per our guidelines, so I think it's a good question.  I'ved added tags of `homework` and `self-study`. Feel free to delete whichever one doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \delta(u) \delta(t-u) du
$$

Try using the [sifting property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiftingProperty.html) of $\delta(t)$:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(u) \delta(T-u) du = f(T)
$$

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very strong in applying the sifting property yet.

Answer (score 3):

You may also look at the transfer function ($s$-domain) of the two systems:
$$H_1(s)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-s}$$
$$H_2(s)=2e^{s}$$
And the two systems in series will result in $$H_1(s)H_2(s)=1$$
which means they are inverse of each other.

Comment: (+1) but I would say, Z-domain for continuous time impulses ?

Answer (score 2):

in addition to Peter K. who suggested you to use **sifting** property, I would also suggest you to use **convolution** property of **delta** function:

$$ x(t) \star \delta(t-a) = x(t-a) $$

You shall now replace $x(t)$ with the other impulse...

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how I would apply this though. the x(t) function? you mean h1(t)?

Comment: hmm $h_1(t) = \frac12 \delta (t-1)$ and $h_2(t) = 2 \delta (t+1)$ you should have applied convolution property as $h_1(t) \star h_2(t) =  \frac12 \delta (t-1) \star 2 \delta (t+1) = \delta (t-1) \star \delta (t+1) = \delta ((t+1)-1) = \delta (t)$ ... And yes! the two systems are inverses.

Comment: (+1) I think they are the same @Fat32 (the integral in the shifting property is convolution)

Comment: @msm **they** are ? (sifting and convolution property) are not the same things. Multiplication with impulse is sifting: $x(t)\cdot \delta(t-a) = x(a) \delta (t-a)$ where as the convolution with impulse **shifts** the signal. I think when two impulses happen they seem to be the same.

Comment: In that sense, you are right. I was referring to the integral form (sifting property).